# Storing arrays in a csv file in Python

Tags: python, csv

I am saving the identity array `A` to a `csv` file. But for `n=83`, I see that the array is saved to a single row as shown below. However, `for n=84`, the array is saved but in a weird format as shown below. How can I save the array for `n=84` and for much larger `n` in the same format as for `n=83`?

```
import numpy as np
import csv

A=np.identity(n)
print(A)

with open(rf"output.csv", 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow([[A]])
```

The data when `n=83`

[image]

The data when `n=84`

[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on what exactly you are trying to achive — in particular, how do you want the array elements to be mapped to CSV columns and rows? Also, when troubleshooting CSV writing issues, always look at the CSV file in a text editor, not by opening it in a spreadsheet program like Excel or Numbers, because that usually adds an extra layer of confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Try with numpy display options:

```
import re

with (np.printoptions(threshold=np.inf, linewidth=np.inf),
      open('output.csv', 'w') as f):
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    A_repr = re.sub('\s+', ' ', repr(A))
    writer.writerow([[A_repr]])
```

Comment: This is not working.

Comment: If you use `quoting` parameter `writer = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)` does it work?

Comment: Still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the functionality of double brackets, [[A]]
but by iterating manually, line by line, it seems to be working:

```
import csv
A = [[I, I*2, I*3] for I in range(1, 50)] # test data
with open(rf"output,csv", 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for i in A:
        writer.writerow(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, just add `newline=""` to [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) :

```
import numpy as np
import csv

n = 83
A = np.identity(n)

with open("output.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow([A])
```

Output (*.csv*) :

[image]

Comment: For some reason, this doesn't seem to work for large ```n``` say, ```100```.

Comment: Working fine here. Can you open the csv generated in notepad (instead of Excel) and share a screenshot ?

Comment: For ```n=100```, I am using ```writer.writerow([[A]])```  instead of using ```writer.writerow([A])``` and I get this.

Comment: You need to use `writer.writerow([A])` as I mentionned.

Comment: Is there a specific reason? I want the code to work for large ```n```.  Using ```writer.writerow([A])``` doesn't help.